# Как перебрать элементы DOM на jquerry?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Не получается обратится к элементу с индексом(elem[i]).
Понять не могу, что не так делаю

HTML

````
   ```<div class="news-page__all-news__pages container">
  <a class="news-page__all-news__pages-item-back"><i class="icon-ic_arrow_small"></i></a>
  <a class="news-page__all-news__pages-item news-page__all-news__pages-item-active">1</a>
  <a class="news-page__all-news__pages-item">2</a>
  <a class="news-page__all-news__pages-item">3</a>
  <a class="news-page__all-news__pages-item">4</a>
  <a class="news-page__all-news__pages-item-space">...</a>
  <a class="news-page__all-news__pages-item">15</a>
  <a class="news-page__all-news__pages-item-next"><i class="icon-ic_arrow_small"></i></a>
</div>```
````

JS

````
  $('.news-page__all-news__pages-item').each(function(i,elem) {
  $('.news-page__all-news__pages-item').removeClass("news-page__all-news__pages-item-active");
  $(elem[i]).addClass("news-page__all-news__pages-item-active");
 });
 });```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.news-page__all-news__pages-item').removeClass("news-page__all-news__pages-item-active");
$('.news-page__all-news__pages-item').each(function(i, elem) {
  if (i == 2) {
    $(elem).addClass("news-page__all-news__pages-item-active");
  }
});
```

---

```
$('.news-page__all-news__pages-item').
  removeClass("news-page__all-news__pages-item-active").
  eq(2).
  addClass("news-page__all-news__pages-item-active");
```